# How can I keep-alive the watir(chrome-driver) longer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, watir

I have a long-running scraping work on selenium(Ruby Watir).

But after 60 minutes I get this error :

```
Net::ReadTimeout: Net::ReadTimeout with #<TCPSocket:(closed)>
```

My code :

```
args = %w[disable-extions headless disable-gpu disable-dev-shm-usage disable-software-rasterizer no-sandbox]
browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome, options: {args: args}
Watir.default_timeout = 999999
```

How can I keep-alive the chrome-driver longer?

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
 args = %w[disable-extions headless disable-gpu disable-dev-shm-usage disable-software-rasterizer no-sandbox]
 client = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Http::Default.new
 client.read_timeout = 120 # seconds
 driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome, options: {args: args}, http_client: client
 browser=Watir::Browser.new driver
```

This would wait for 120 seconds for page load

And don't change the `default_timeout` because that's not for page load instead that's for element to be present.